# Using Process.spawn as a replacement for Process.fork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, fork

My development environment is a Windows machine running ruby 1.9.3p125 (RubyInstaller) and rails 3.2.8.

One issue that comes up, time and again, when using third-party gems, is the lack of fork() on Windows. This has recently hindered my ability to use pretty much any distributed test running gem (like [these](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/distributed_testing)), due to their dependence on fork.

Some older questions on StackOverflow have attempted to find a resolution to this same problem, but were either before the addition of Process.spawn into ruby, or were from people forced to use an older version of Ruby, for some other reason.

One of the proposed solutions is to use Cygwin to gain fork() support, which is simply out of the question for this - I think I would prefer to switch to Linux fully, before that.

Another proposed solution has been using the [win32-process gem](https://github.com/djberg96/win32-process) to gain fork() support. Fork support was removed from the most recent version (0.7.0), and using the next oldest version (0.6.6), which does (sort-of) support fork does not seem to work, at least for running any of the distributed testing gems that I have tried (Spork, Parallel tests, Hydra, Specjour, practically all of them). Interestingly enough, the author of the gem alludes, in the readme, to Process.spawn being an acceptable workaround for Process.fork.

I have seen a lot of information either implying, or [stating outright](http://ujihisa.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-run-external-command.html) that spawn can be used as a replacement for fork, on Windows, with Ruby 1.9. I have spent a fair amount of time playing with this, basically trying to replace Process.fork with Process.spawn in several of the referenced gems, with no success. It seems to me that perhaps the behavior is similar, but not exactly the same. For example, it is unclear whether spawn actually copies the entire process in the same way the fork does, or simply creates a new process with the supplied arguments. It is also unclear as to whether the spawn method even accepts another ruby method as an argument, or only a system command. The docs seem to imply that it is only a command, but a method seems to work (sort-of), but I may be doing things incorrectly. I think that for some things, fork was just used to create a "cheap thread", in previous ruby versions that did not support threading. However, it seems that these distributed testing gems may legitimately rely on the full functionality of fork(), in order to maintain the project state, and to not load the whole ruby environment for every test. This is a bit outside of my normal programming duties and experience, so I may be making some incorrect assumptions.

So, my question is, can Process.spawn be used relatively simply to achieve the same outcome as Process.fork, in all cases? I am beginning to suspect not, but if so, could someone please post an example of how one would go about making the transformation?

Comment: According to the documentation, Process.spawn simply creates a new process, and does not attempt to copy the state of the current process into the new one.  That's to be expected; copying the state of the process, while theoretically possible in an interpreted language, is too expensive to happen by default.  Unless Ruby has some kind of snapshot save/restore functionality, or there is some way of making it implement fork, code using fork is likely to need at least some redesign to make it work on Windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT**: There is one common use case of `fork()` that can be replaced with `spawn()` -- the `fork()`--`exec()` combo. A lot of older (and modern) UNIX applications, when they want to spawn another process, will first fork, and then make an `exec` call (`exec` replaces the current process with another). This doesn't actually need `fork()`, which is why it can be replaced with `spawn()`. So, this:

```
if(!fork())
  exec("dir")
end
```

can be replaced with:

```
Process.spawn("dir")
```

If any of the gems are using `fork()` like this, the fix is easy. Otherwise, it is almost impossible.

---

**EDIT**: The reason why win32-process' implementation of `fork()` doesn't work is that (as far as I can tell from the docs), it basically *is* `spawn()`, which isn't `fork()` at all.

---

No, I don't think it can be done. You see, `Process.spawn` creates a new process with the default blank state and native code. So, while I can do something like `Process.spawn('dir')` will start a *new*, *blank* process running `dir`, it won't clone *any* of the current process' state. It's only connection to your program is the parent - child connection.

You see, `fork()` is a very low level call. For example, on Linux, what `fork()` basically does is this: first, a new process is created with *exactly* cloned register state. Then, Linux does a copy-on-write reference to all of the parent process' pages. Linux then clones some other process flags. Obviously, all of these operations can only be done by the kernel, and the Windows kernel doesn't have the facilities to do that (and can't be patched to either).

Technically, only native programs need the OS for some sort of `fork()`-like support. Any layer of code needs the cooperation of the layer above it to do something like `fork()`. So while native C code needs the cooperation of the kernel to fork, Ruby theoretically only needs the cooperation of the interpreter to do a fork. However, the Ruby interpreter does not have a snapshot/restore feature, which would be necessarily to implement a fork. Because of this, normal Ruby fork is achieved by forking the interpreter itself, not the Ruby program.

So, while if you could patch the Ruby interpreter to add a stop/start and snapshot/restore feature, you could do it, but otherwise? I don't think so.

So what are your options? This is what I can think of:

- Patch the Ruby interpreter
- Patch the code that uses `fork()` to maybe use threads or spawn
- Get a UNIX (I suggest this one)
- Use Cygwin

Edit 1:
I wouldn't suggest using Cygwin's fork, as it involves special Cygwin process tables, there is **no** copy-on-write, which makes it very inefficient. Also, it involves a lot of jumping back and forth and a lot of copying. Avoid it if possible. Also, because Windows provides no facilities to copy address spaces, forks are very likely to fail, and will quite a lot of the time (see [here](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html)).

Comment: This seems pretty good except for the part about a C "interpreter".

Comment: @DavidGrayson: What do you mean? I don't really understand what you meant my that.

Comment: The C code here is compiled, not interpreted.  Gcc is a compiler, not interpreter.  Which interpreter are you thinking of?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Whoops! Subtle misunderstanding here. I ment the Ruby interpreter *written* in C, not a C interpreter. I'll fix that.

Comment: Nice breakdown - thanks! It's basically what I was afraid of, though. I'm leaning toward switching environments, too, although I don't relish the thought of maintaining two separate environments.

Comment: @iioiooioo: You'll be much happier on Linux, I'm sure. You get all of the other benifits like security too.

Comment: Honestly, if it weren't for TortoiseGit, I probably would have switched a long time ago. I'm more reluctant to lose that than I am to use a VM for .net development. Oh well.

Comment: @iioiooioo: There are a lot of good git tools for linux, and if you ask me, it's best in the terminal anyway. Also, depending on what parts of .NET you're using, you might be able to use the Mono framework, the open source implementation of .NET.