# Ruby version control for windows (not pik)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to use `pik` but it looks like outdated, they using rubyforge.org but that website is not working and I cant download ruby versions using `pik_install` command.

Is there any other tools?

Comment: Say no to windows, say hello to linux - best decision ever!

Comment: You might get a kick out of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220024/using-process-spawn-as-a-replacement-for-process-fork (I ended up switching to Ubuntu for dev, BTW - runs tests much more quickly)

Comment: Also, FWIW, outdated or not, I did end up having pretty good luck with pik and RubyInstaller, for Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Windows isn't an ideal experience, the Windows environment itself is non-standard compared to other POSIX-style operating systems.

For example, [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) works on Windows only if [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) is installed.

You may find that using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) to manage multiple independent virtual machines is easier than trying to get a number of Ruby versions to co-exist on your local machine. Each of these can be used, and discarded, without impacting your main development environment.

Comment: is ubuntu good for ruby development?

Comment: Ubuntu is great for Ruby development.  As is most any other Linux, BSD or Mac platform.