# How to enable colors on console for guard-minitest on Windows (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, guard

I'm running windows 7 (32-bit) trying to learn Rails development.

I'm trying to get my guard tests running with colors on the console, but I can't seem to find any way to get it to work. It just displays all white. I've tried the regular command line console and the git bash console that comes with the rails installer package, same result.

Gemfile

```
  group :test do
  # main test suite
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
  gem 'wdm',                '0.1.0'
end
```

When I run the tests, it suggests installing the win32console gem, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: It's just not worth it....
http://stackoverflow.com/q/12220024/525478
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
http://www.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I guess not. I can't find anything on this. ANSICON didn't work for me. It's not critical to get the colors working, but it's just bugging me.