# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cygwin

I didn't wanted to use Rails Installer. I choose to install everything with cygwin as it provides Unix like shell functionality. I typed `ruby` && `rails`. Installed everything what ever cygwin could provide related to ruby and rails. Then I tried to make my first application but It showed me this below error. What is it that I possibly broke?

Is it that I am missing some C formulas? Or some Ruby libraries?

Pleaes scroll to bottom to see the error.

```
$ rails new app
       exist
   identical  README.rdoc
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  config.ru
   identical  .gitignore
   identical  Gemfile
       exist  app
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
   identical  app/assets/images/.keep
   identical  app/mailers/.keep
   identical  app/models/.keep
   identical  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
   identical  app/models/concerns/.keep
       exist  bin
   identical  bin/bundle
   identical  bin/rails
   identical  bin/rake
   identical  bin/setup
       exist  config
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/application.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
    conflict  config/secrets.yml
Overwrite /home/Abhimanyu Aryan/app/config/secrets.yml? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh 
       force  config/secrets.yml
       exist  config/environments
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
       exist  config/initializers
   identical  config/initializers/assets.rb
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
   identical  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
   identical  config/initializers/session_store.rb
   identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       exist  config/locales
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  config/boot.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
       exist  db
   identical  db/seeds.rb
       exist  lib
       exist  lib/tasks
   identical  lib/tasks/.keep
       exist  lib/assets
   identical  lib/assets/.keep
       exist  log
   identical  log/.keep
       exist  public
   identical  public/404.html
   identical  public/422.html
   identical  public/500.html
   identical  public/favicon.ico
   identical  public/robots.txt
       exist  test/fixtures
   identical  test/fixtures/.keep
       exist  test/controllers
   identical  test/controllers/.keep
       exist  test/mailers
   identical  test/mailers/.keep
       exist  test/models
   identical  test/models/.keep
       exist  test/helpers
   identical  test/helpers/.keep
       exist  test/integration
   identical  test/integration/.keep
   identical  test/test_helper.rb
       exist  tmp/cache
       exist  tmp/cache/assets
       exist  vendor/assets/javascripts
   identical  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
       exist  vendor/assets/stylesheets
   identical  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20151121-9652-2lj58.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
rm -f
rm -f generator.so  *.o  *.bak mkmf.log .*.time

make "DESTDIR="
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR     -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration    -o generator.o -c generator.c
rm -f generator.so
gcc -shared -o generator.so generator.o -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -fstack-protector -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import    -lruby220  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:254: recipe for target 'generator.so' failed
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/Abhimanyu Aryan/.gem/ruby/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/Abhimanyu Aryan/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: You need to install `libgmp` and `libcrypt` into cygwin.

Comment: You might be better off in a VM - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220024/using-process-spawn-as-a-replacement-for-process-fork

Comment: @mudasobwa still same error

Comment: Have you installed those libraries _with their development files_?

Comment: I installed everything that is provided with the name libgmp and libcrypt