# Running localhost:3000 using Ruby on rails with pgadmin3 database i get following errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql

Can anyone help me fix this problem?? when i run localhost:3000 i encounter this?

> "could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)

Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)

Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?..... Now, again when i try to run "net start postgresql-9.5" in CMD line it says

> 'system error 5 has occured,access is denied'.

what is wrong i cant understand?

Comment: Rails and Windows don't play well together. Dual boot some version of Linux and save yourself hours of attempting to debug errors like this one

Comment: Or a VM... Really, SomeSchmo is right, it's just not worth it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220024/using-process-spawn-as-a-replacement-for-process-fork, there aren't even parallels for some of the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I know in windows it's struggling to learn rails but if you want to continue below is some tips when I test running rails with windows

1. for rails installer, you can download from http://railsinstaller.org/en it include git , ruby and rails
2. for postgres, I think it's easier to install from [this site](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/), you just follow windows instruction and make sure you write down the password as you will need it later for your database.yml (database configuration)
3. after you install both programs, when you want to open command prompt, make sure you choose command prompt with ruby on rails, as this command prompt will include git, ruby and rails command.

hopefully can help